# knockoutjs viewmodel bind with ajax and computed

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am starting with knockoutjs but i am wondering how i can do this. I want to add src attribute which one will contain static and dynamic content. please check bottom

```
var viewModel = {
    title : ko.observable("title"),
    description : ko.observable("description"),
    poster : ko.observable("poster"),
    imdb : ko.observable("imdb")
    movie : ko.computed(function(){
        return 'https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=search&list='+this.title()+'&autoplay=1&origin=http://filmmovies.in&fs=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0&loop=1&color=white&controls=0&mode=opaque'
    })
};
$.post('/movies/index').then(function(data){
    ko.applyBindings({movies: data});
});
```

========================================
request response

```
[
  {"title":"Iron Man","description":"asdf kasdf <H1>hsdifaf</H1>","poster":"http://www.google.com","imdb":"viapn.webdeveloper@gmail.com","createdAt":"2017-05-02T07:42:28.864Z","updatedAt":"2017-05-02T07:42:28.864Z","id":10},
  {"title":"Iron Man","description":"asdf kasdf <H1>hsdifaf</H1>","poster":"http://www.google.com","imdb":"viapn.webdeveloper@gmail.com","createdAt":"2017-05-02T06:53:51.984Z","updatedAt":"2017-05-02T06:53:51.984Z","id":1},
  {"title":"Iron Man","description":"asdf kasdf <H1>hsdifaf</H1>","poster":"http://www.google.com","imdb":"viapn.webdeveloper@gmail.com","createdAt":"2017-05-02T06:55:20.245Z","updatedAt":"2017-05-02T06:55:20.245Z","id":3},
  {"title":"Iron Man","description":"asdf kasdf <H1>hsdifaf</H1>","poster":"http://www.google.com","imdb":"viapn.webdeveloper@gmail.com","createdAt":"2017-05-02T07:12:45.620Z","updatedAt":"2017-05-02T07:12:45.620Z","id":4}
]
```

Comment: is the data from the request is an array?

Comment: yes data from request is an array but every element of array is json object

Comment: what problem are you facing with the code you've shared? you would like to go through this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should better describe your problem so we can be more helpfull
Where do you want to bind that src attribute, how do you implement your bind, and the most important "describe your goal in theory"
I am having a hard time figuring out what the actual question is

Answer (score 0):

go through this fiddle it will give you on how to use listing

http://jsfiddle.net/emrefatih47/Mmt9F/
it is a sample this is what actually you are looking for
// Contained Model

```
function SomeModel() {
    this.Firstname = ko.observable();
    this.Lastname = ko.observable();
}

// View Model


function SomeViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    this.ArrayOfModels = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);

    this.GetModelsByAjax = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/echo/json/',
            data: {
                json: JSON.stringify([{
                Firstname: "Bob",
                Lastname: "Smith"},
            {
                Firstname: "Ted",
                Lastname: "Smith"}]),
                delay: 0
            },
            context: this,
            success: function(data) {
                self.SuccessfullyRetrievedModelsFromAjax(data);
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    };

    this.SuccessfullyRetrievedModelsFromAjax = function(models) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(models, self.ArrayOfModels);
    }
```

;
}

```
ko.applyBindings(new SomeViewModel());
```